# What is the purpose of allowing infix operators to have no an associativity?

Tags: swift, operators

**Question 1:** What is the purpose of allowing infix operators to have no associativity? (Possibly someone can give an example of a custom operator where this is preferable over actually including some associativity?)

**Question 2:** Is it possible to set a default associativity for infix operators, used for operators that have none?

---

We can define a custom infix operator without entering any associativity for it, e.g.

```
/* no associativity */
infix operator +| {
    precedence 140
}

/* left associativity */
infix operator *| {
    associativity left
    precedence 140
}
```

Now, one could assume that using an infix operator without associativity (`+|` above) next to one with associativity (`*|` above)---where both operators have same precedence---would behave the same way as if both operators had the same associativity. However, this is not the case

```
func +| (lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int {
    return lhs+rhs
}

func *| (lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int {
    return lhs*rhs
}

let a : Int = 1 +| 2 *| 3
/* Error: non-associative operator is adjacent to 
          operator of same precedence               */
```

If we add `associativity left` to the definition of `+|` above, the code runs fine (as expected)

```
/* no associativity */
infix operator +| {
    associativity left
    precedence 140
}

// ...

let a : Int = 1 +| 2 *| 3
/* 9, OK ((1+2)*3 = 9) */
```

If I have a look at the native Swift operators (Cmd-click *Swift* in `import Swift`), I can't find a single infix operators that is without associativity.

Why are we allowed to define infix operators without associativity, is there a possible use for such operators? Is it possible to set a default associativity for infix operators, such that operators with associativity will behave as if having the default associativity?

Comment: The  associativity defaults to "none". `==`, `<`, `<<` and some more have associativity none. It forces you – for example – to set parentheses in `a << b << c`.

Comment: @MartinR Ah, I missed the explicit "none" cases. I think this little comment answers both of my questions, actually. Thanks!